# How to count the same column under two different situation in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Suppose a demo table course with following schema

```
courseId    keyId
   2         0
   2         3
   2         4
   3         5
   3         0
   3         0
```

The expected output of the query should count the number of courseId with 0 separately and others seperately.
Example

```
courseId    ZeroCount    NonZeroCount
   2           1             2
   3           2             1
```

Please help me I am stuck on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySQL use

```
select courseId, 
       sum(keyId = 0) as ZeroCount, 
       sum(keyId <> 0) as NonZeroCount
from your_table
group by courseId
```

and ANSI standard SQL is

```
select courseId, 
       sum(case when keyId = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ZeroCount, 
       sum(case when keyId <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NonZeroCount
from your_table
group by courseId
```